# How to hide columns in r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking to hide 2 columns in my R dataframe. I have tried to download the "gt" package, but I am unable to. Is there another function to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide 2 columns"? Do you want to remove these columns from the `data.frame` entirely? Or hide them when printing using a specific function/method (you mention `gt` which produces tables for HTML/PDF docs)? We're missing details. Also please include sample data and a description/example of your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library("gapminder")
library("dplyr")
library("gt")

tab_1 <-
  penguins %>%  # table name
  dplyr::filter(species == "Adelie") %>% 
  head(10) %>%
  gt() %>%
  cols_hide(columns = c(sex, year)) # columns you want to hide

print(tab_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here there is an example that you can try with `gt`:

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

gapminder %>%
  filter(country == "Germany") %>%
  head(10) %>%
  gt() %>%
  cols_hide(columns = c(lifeExp, pop))
```